# Почему фон элемента html (и элемента body) выпирает за пределы рамки, которая определяет границы блочного элемента?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привет. Я задал элементу html высоту 300 пикселей и зеленую рамку. зеленая рамка как раз и отрисовалась под эту высоту, а черный фон почему-то выпер (на всю страницу вылез) за пределы рамки, хотя фон должен внутри находиться. 
Высота блочного элемента определяется содержимым. на это и рамка зеленая указывает, а черный фон должен быть в пределах рамки. Не понятно. Если отключить эти стили для элемента html, то окажется, что для  body ситуация такая же - синий фон выпирает (на всю страницу) за пределы блока с красной рамкой. Тоже непонятно. Для всех других элементов все окей - фон находится в пределах рамки (бордера) блочного элемента.

Comment: Для лучшей читаемости приводите код текстом, а не картинкой. Кроме того так будет легче его подкорректировать, опробовать в ответе.

Comment: код вставляться нормально не хотел

Comment: Возможно, стоит уделить немного времени на то, чтобы изучить markdown-разметку? Вставили текст в поле редактирования, выделили код, нажали кнопку "пример кода" - собственно и всё. Markdown-разметка достаточно популярная вещь, например, этот навык пригодится вам на гитхабе.

Answer (score 1):

Фон, выставленный для элементов html, body применяется для всего вьюпорта. Подробнее об этом в [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds).